# android FileProvider issue when space in folder or file name and share

Tags: android

I have very strange issue with FileProvider:

```
File file = "/storage/emulated/0/my testing/test.png"
```

in order to share it:

```
            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            ctx,
            ctx.getPackageName() + ".provider",
            file
        );
```

result uri is

content://ta.my.provider/external/my%2520testing/test.png

I have overwritten the openFile in FileProvider

```
        @Override
    public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(@NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
        return super.openFile(uri,mode);
    }
```

and I can see that file provider fails to handle the space (%2520)!!!

What I am not sure is what is causing the error? Please note I do nothing special,

use provider to get uri from file and then the share app comes back with the same uri, so I would expect it to work?

Of course I can hack the uri but I am not sure Google can have such a simple error, may be I am doing something worng?

V

Comment: Why do you care about that %20 for a space char? You can just use that uri. No one will complain. It is just a needed encoding for an uri. Which app that you used it for could not handle that uri? Further i would expect only %20 for a space. Not a %2520.

Comment: `File file = "/storage/emulated/0/my testing/test.png"` That is a pretty strange constuct. I have seen File file = File("/storage/emulated/0/my testing/test.png") before though. Please log value of file.getAbsolutePath().